# Login with hashing function error

Tags: php, hash

I'm familiar with crypt systems but I have trying to implement some hashing function but I can't login after user is registered. This is the class for hashing that I have

```
class PassHash {

// blowfish
private static $algo = '$2a';

// cost parameter
private static $cost = '$10';

// mainly for internal use
public static function unique_salt() {
    return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
} 
// this will be used to generate a hash
public static function hash($password) {

    return crypt($password,
                self::$algo .
                self::$cost .
                '$' . self::unique_salt());

}
// this will be used to compare a password against a hash
public static function check_password($hash, $password) {

    $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);

    $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt);

    return ($hash == $new_hash); 
}
}
```

This is the login form

```
include 'misc/database.inc.php';
require ("misc/hash.php");
if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) {
$pdo = Database::connect();
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=""; 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1"); //Limiting result to one only.

$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$res  = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // Asks to fetch as an object.

$password = $res->password;
if (PassHash::checkHash($password, $_POST['password'])) {


if ($res['level'] == 1)
{
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $res['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname']  = $res['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['email']     = $res['email']; 

    header( "location: users/main.php");   
}
else 
{
        header("location: index.php");              
}
} else 
{
  echo "can't enter";
}
```

I keep getting `error`. Also is it normal on same password (i tested with `123321`) to store different `hash` every time or there is error also in register form?

here is the userAdd file.

```
if ( !empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'] )) 
            {               

            // keep track post values
            $username= $_POST['username'];

            $pw = new PassHash();
            $myHash = $pw->hash($_POST['password']);

            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];                          


                        // update data

            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = "UPDATE users set username = ?, password = ?, firstname = ?, lastname = ?, email = ?, user_image = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q-execute(array($username,$myHash,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$pathForDB,$user_id));
```

Comment: Is just going into `else { echo "error"; }` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think i found your specific error. 
You are sending a blank password variable to be validated, have a look here, i commented the essential part of my editing.

```
require ("misc/hash.php");
if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) {
$pdo = Database::connect();
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=""; 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1"); //Limiting result to one only.

$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$res  = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // Asks to fetch as an object.

// PASSWORD IS STILL EMPTY HERE!
// Must fill it out, to be the hashed password from database
$password = $res->password;

if (PassHash::check_password($password, $_POST['password'])) {
```

Does this fix the issue for you?

Could you try this?

```
class PassHash {

    protected function salter() {
        $salt = "";
        $salt_chars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));

        for($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) {
          $salt .= $salt_chars[array_rand($salt_chars)];
        }

        return $salt;
    }

      public function hash($input, $rounds = 7)
      {
        return crypt($input, sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds) . $this->salter());
      }

      public function checkHash($password, $hash) {
        if( crypt($password, $hash) == $hash ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

      }
}


$pw = new PassHash();
$myHash = $pw->hash("1234");

if( $pw->checkHash("1234", $myHash) ) {
    echo "I did it!";
} else {
    echo "I diden't do it!";
}
```

Comment: Like this is save just this in password field in database `*0` no matter what password I enter.

Comment: Yes, like this is working. But the problem with login is still exist. Just doesn't login.. it's going into `else { echo "error"; }` statement

Comment: Updated current login form with your code (check in question) also updated also the add user script. Now I see that password is updated in DB. And still when I try to log I go into `else`

Comment: Another problem.. I have users with password hashed with `sha1` and I'm able to log. Is this supposed to be like this? Actually I log whit whatever password I enter :)